# "The referenced component could not be found"

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm attempting to build this project: https://github.com/Draco18s/NovelAPI/tree/9f99af461e4161ed4ba95e4721ec4b35cfd00ff2

But I've been stuck on a brick wall where none of the references for NuGet packages are working. I've got all the packages downloaded, I can see them in the package manager window and even see them in the project's directory. Despite this, the project itself just cannot find any of the packages and is throwing errors for all code involved. I added a bunch of screenshots to show what's going on.

I've been burning a lot of time on all of the solutions I can find online, but nothing is working. I haven't worked with NuGet very much so there's probably something obvious I'm missing and I figured I'll ask for help here at this point. Thanks everyone!

[Broken references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKZic.png)

[Warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9g7C.png)

[Nuget packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IQrf.png)

[Packages on my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2CEt.png)

[Errors everywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMePt.png)

Most solutions that I've been finding online hint towards there being something wrong with hard coded paths. But fixing that in the project settings did nothing either. As far as I can tell, all the dots are as connected as can be. But something has to be missing if the project is as broken as it is?

[Reference paths do nothing either](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11n11.png)

I've also tried cleaning/rebuilding, pulling the project again, etc all the basics. Those did nothing either.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 - 16.11.23

Comment: make sure your `sln` file is in a folder which is one level above than the `csproj` file. The references have hardcoded relative paths which expect this heirarchy.

Comment: If `using System;` throws a compiler error then Visual Studio has got its virtual knickers in a twist. I don't know why this happens (but it, and similarly confusing things, do happen), but what I'd do is... 1) Close all VS windows 2) Delete the `bin` and `obj` folders from all the projects (assuming those are your output folders and they don't contain any of your code files) 3) Open VS and try building your solution again. Good luck!